# After installation of shopware 6 it's showing "not found" and "url not found on this server" error all over the page

Tags: ubuntu, shopware, shopware6

I am trying to install shopware 6 on ubuntu os and on LOCALHOST, and after installation it was showing this errors all over the page,
[image]

I have installed shopware using below command:

```
composer create-project shopware/production:6.3 shopware

bin/console system:setup

bin/console system:install --create-database --basic-setup
```

this is my .htaccess
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    # Restrict access to VCS directories
    RedirectMatch 404 /\\.(svn|git|hg|bzr|cvs)(/|$)

    # Restrict access to root folder files
    RedirectMatch 404 /(composer\.(json|lock|phar)|README\.md|\.gitignore|.*\.dist|\.env.*)$
</IfModule>
```

I am newbie in both ubuntu and shopware development,
I am trying this for days but finally when i done with installation i reach to this wall and could not know what to do?

can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your document root is not pointing to the `public` folder, hence why you currently have to navigate to `shopware/public` which is not intended to be the case.

You may want to [create a virtual host file](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-20-04#step-4-creating-new-virtual-host-files) to set the document root to the `public` directory.

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/shopware/public
  <Directory /var/www/html/shopware/public>
      AllowOverride all
      Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: how can i direct that in my current setup, I have install apache2 
sorry if my question found little dumb but I am new in ubuntu so not familiar.
should I edit my apache2 config file for this? @dneustadt

Comment: from your given link (from step - 6) as  I am at my localhost, I have set up the 
some domain in my local like "http://shopware.test/" it's showing apache default page.
so now where I needed to have add this code you have provide ?

Comment: Just edit the `*.conf` file you created for your domain and change the document root and directory to point to your `shopware/public` directory as in the example above. Restart the server and that should be all.

Comment: YES !! i have created the new setup for "shopware.test" and it's working and as you instruct I have directed the path to public and now it's working.
@dneustadt thanks sir

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this just for more details, as it will be helpfull in installation of shopware 6 (6.4) in ubuntu 22.04

Here's a step-by-step guide on how to install Shopware 6 on Ubuntu 22.04:

1. First, download the Shopware 6 ZIP file from the official website or GitHub repository.
2. Unzip the downloaded file using the following command:

   `unzip shopware.zip`
3. Once you have extracted the files, set the appropriate permissions for the Shopware root directory using the following command:

   `sudo chown -R www-data: /var/www/shopware.test/public_html`
4. Next, create a new Apache virtual host configuration file using the following command:

   `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/shopware.test.conf`
5. In the newly created file, add the following lines to configure the virtual host:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName shopware.test
      DocumentRoot /var/www/shopware.test/public_html
      <Directory /var/www/shopware.test/public_html>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
     </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
6. Verify that the Apache configuration is correct using the following command:

   `sudo apache2ctl configtest`
7. If there are no syntax errors in the configuration, reload the Apache service to apply the changes:

   `sudo systemctl reload apache2`
8. Set the appropriate permissions once again to ensure that the Apache user has access to the Shopware root directory:

   `sudo chown -R www-data: /var/www/shopware.test/public_html`
9. Enable the Apache rewrite module using the following command:

   `sudo a2enmod rewrite`
10. Restart the Apache service to apply the changes:

```
`sudo systemctl restart apache2`
```

You should now be able to access your Shopware 6 installation by visiting the URL http://shopware.test in your web browser.

Comment: This `sudo a2enmod rewrite` with `sudo systemctl restart apache2` was the real trick. By default ModRewrite is seemingly off in Apache2 by default.